# Is there a way to print 2 equally sum sub list, of a list?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

So i have this code here which works and returns True, if there is 2 sub lists with the same sum (1/2 of the total sum)
read more about [Partition Equal Subset Sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-equal-subset-sum/)

Example:

```
s = Solution()
print(s.canPartition([3,10,9,2]))
# output [3, 9] , [10, 2]
```

My code iterate the indexes, and each iteration split for 2 ways - first way is adding the value to sum.. second way is move on without adding the value.
if one of the ways returns True it's says that a solution have been found.

Time complexity should be 2^n but because of dynamic programming it have been reduced to O(n)

Now my issue that i have tried to figure out is how to backtrack the "True root" and print all the items that belongs to the root (hopefully half of the total sum)

What i mean by "true root" is somehow, when i return the First True (it means i have found the sum) and for that way i already have the items.
Example :

```
[3,10,9,2]
# output [3, 9] , [10, 2]

Tree of recursive:

          []
         /   \
       [3]    []
      /   \     \
 [3,10]   [3]    [] 
   /      /        \
        [3,9] # THE Root returing firt true
```

Code:

```
class Solution:
    def canPartition(self, nums: List[int]) -> bool:
        def helper(s1, s2, i, memo):

            # recursion

            hashed = (s1 + s2)
            if hashed in memo.keys():
                return memo[hashed]

            if s1 == s2:    # we have 2 groups of sums that sums total
                return True

            if s1 > s2: # we have too big group
                return False

            if i == len(nums):  # the end
                return s1 == s2

            # 2 options : move to next index with/witohut counting index
            memo[hashed] = helper(s1 + nums[i], s2, i + 1, memo) or helper(s1, s2, i + 1, memo)

            return memo[hashed]

        # begin

        s = sum(nums)   # sum
        memo = {}   # dynamic programing

        if s % 2 == 0:  # odd sum can't be divided equally
            return helper(0, s // 2, 0, memo)

        return False
```

Example for better understanding my desired output:

```
s = Solution()
print(s.canPartition([3,10,9,2]))
# output [3, 9] , [10, 2]
```

Comment: It would be easier to make a suggestion if you could explain your code a little bit. What is "true root" and what do you mean by the items belong to it?

Comment: in a recursive way, I don't know how to backtrack the list, but if you create all possible partition to 2 parts of your list and compare the bits you'll have the list in hand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36509227/all-ways-of-partitioning-a-list-into-two-non-empty-lists

Comment: thanks @trigonom  i've updated with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A helpful hint**

Your `helper` function either returns `True` or `False`. Before it returns `True`, try printing the last element `nums[i]` you considered in that recursion.

**Another hint**

In `helper`, you are making two recursive calls.

1. `helper(s1 + nums[i], s2, i + 1, memo)`
2. `helper(s1, s2, i + 1, memo)`

If the result of step 1. is `True`, this means that you are keeping `nums[i]` in your sum. You need to split that `OR` statement, in order to find this out. When you split it, if step 1. is `True`, then you do not need to run step 2.

Comment: how can i do that? since i have OR between the recursive calls.. 1 True statement is enough for every root to become True. 
Look at my base cases

Comment: @Moshe I explained a little more. Does this help?